# Subclassing Delegate Issue

Tags: ios, iphone, oop, multiplayer, mcsession

I create an MCSession in a parent class with this:

```
- (void) setUpMultipeer{
    //  Setup peer ID
    self.myPeerID = [[MCPeerID alloc] initWithDisplayName:[UIDevice currentDevice].name];

    //  Setup session
    self.mySession = [[MCSession alloc] initWithPeer:self.myPeerID];
    self.mySession.delegate = self;

    //  Setup BrowserViewController
    self.browserVC = [[MCBrowserViewController alloc] initWithServiceType:@"chat" session:self.mySession];
    self.browserVC.delegate = self;

    //  Setup Advertiser
    self.advertiser = [[MCAdvertiserAssistant alloc] initWithServiceType:@"chat" discoveryInfo:nil session:self.mySession];
    [self.advertiser start];
}
```

I have two child classes that are each subclasses of the parent class. I try to log the number of connected peers in each subclass, both return 0. In addition, when logging `self.mySession`I get this:

```
mySession:<MCSession: 0x15d7aae0 MyPeerID = <MCPeerID: 0x15d7b360 DisplayName = Eric's iPhone> SecurityIdentity = (null) EncryptionPreference = Optional ConnectedPeers = (
) Delegate = <ChildViewController: 0x15d867f0>>
```

I never set the delegate to the child, but it appears to think the MCSession Delegate has been changed to the child instead of staying with the parent. Each Child View Controller says it is the delegate, I would think for this to work each child VC should say the parent is the delegate. What am I missing?

ALSO: I'm using storyboard. Both Child VC's are control-dragged push segues embedded in a NavigationController. NavController > Parent >Child 1 & Child 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating an object from a *subclass* doesn't mean a separate instance from the *super class* will be created too. You'll *only* have ***one*** object which ***is a*** `ChildViewController` and a `SuperViewController` at the same time.

When the above code is executed, the `self` keyword references to the actual instance of `ChildViewController` which is also, at the same time, an instance of `SuperViewController` too.

And if you log the `self` keyword in the subclass and its super class, you will notice that they actually point to the same object in memory.

P.S. You can try `po (SuperViewController *) [[self mySession] delegate]` and you'll get what you expect.